# Calling a Query that Returns in MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ienumerable

I am a beginner in MVC 5. I want to display a list of selected data from database .I've created a controller action that used raw query and an IEnumerable class or model. But the Controller returns an error:

> An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in
>   EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Invalid object name 'tblProduct'.

**My Model is :**

```
   namespace ShoppingCartProject1.Models
   {
   public class tblProduct:IEnumerable<tblProduct>
   {
    [Key]
    public int PId { get; set; }
    public string Pname { get; set; }

    List<tblProduct> mylist = new List<tblProduct>();
    public IEnumerator<tblProduct> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return mylist.GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return this.GetEnumerator();
    }
    public tblProduct this[int index]
    {
        get { return mylist[index]; }
        set { mylist.Insert(index, value); }
    }
}
}
```

**Controller is:**

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SearchResult(string searched)
    {
        if (searched== null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }

        // Commenting out original code to show how to use a raw SQL query.
        //Department department = await db.Departments.FindAsync(id);

        // Create and execute raw SQL query.
        string query = "select * from tblProduct where FREETEXT  (Meta, 'branded')";
        IEnumerable<tblProduct> data = db.Database.SqlQuery<tblProduct>(query);

        if (data == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(data.ToList());
    }
}
}
```

the error is seen pointing toward the return statement.

and **the View :**

```
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
       <img src="~/images/@item.Image1" alt="" class="pro-image-front">
       <img src="~/images/@item.Image2" alt="" class="pro-image-back">
    }
```

what I did :

- checked controller through Breakpoints:
  The data element doesn't get any value from  database.
- changed the model functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the table name you're after isn't "tblProduct" - I'm guessing it's more likely to be "tblProducts", so if you amend your SQL query it should work.

This is assuming you've created that table in the sql database - hard to tell without looking at the schema

```
string query = "select * from tblProducts where FREETEXT  (Meta, 'branded')";
IEnumerable<tblProduct> data = db.Database.SqlQuery<tblProduct>(query);
```

ps. the error looks like it's coming from the return statement because that's where the query is getting actually executed against the db.

Answer (score 0):

Seems the table name is not correct. Try changing it to `yourdbname.dbo.tblProduct`. Try to execute the raw query in SQL Management Studio with the same connection parameters first.